# How to pass a variable in sed command

Tags: sed

I have declared a variable:
username=user2

the contents of the test json is as follows:
{
"name": "user1",
"city": "Texas"
}

I would like to replace the value of name i.e user1 with a variable username
I tried the following command:
sed -i 's/"name": "user1"/"name": $username/g'

The output was:

{
"name": $username,
"city": "Texas"
}

Expected Output is:

{
"name": "user2",
"city": "Texas"
}

How can this be achieved?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with `jq`:

```
jq -c --arg name "$username"  '.name = $name'
```

Assuming your input data is **exactly** as you specified, then the following example works with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/("name"\s*:\s*)"[^"]+"/\1"'"$username"'"/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Tried the jq command and it worked for me :)